# Python digital clock - Import Error: cannot import 'label' from 'tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```py
from tkinter import label, Tk
import time 


app_window = Tk ()
app_window.title("Digital Clock")
app_window.geometry("420x180")
app_window.resizeable(0,0)

text_font = ("Ubuntu", 70, "bold")
background = "#293136"
foreground = "#29362e"
border_width = 25 

label = Label(app_window, font=text_font, bg=background, 
fg=foreground, bd=border_width)
label.grid(row=0, column=1)

def digital_clock():
    time_live = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    label.config(text=time_live)
    label.after(200, digital_clock)

digital_clock()
app_window.mainloop()
```

This program is supposed to run a digital clock. But for some reason I run into an import error. I 've tried using
`from tkinter import *`  but it just wouldn't run.

Comment: you mean `from tkinter import Label, Tk` ?

Comment: It is `from tkinter import Label, Tk` with an capital "L".

Comment: Thanks all. I need to learn how to read.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple digital clock to clarify

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Label
import time

master = Tk()
master.title("My Digital Clock!")

Label(master, font=("Calibri", 30), text="Digital Clock", bg="gray", fg="white").pack()

clock = Label(master, font=("Arial", 55), bg="black", fg="white")
clock.pack()


def get_time():
    timeVar = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p  %d.%m.%Y")
    clock.config(text=timeVar)
    clock.after(200, get_time)


get_time()

master.mainloop()
```